# SearchView with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have a single `Activity` app where I put a `SearchView` on the topbar. I am struggling since there are like thousands of manuals/tutorials on implementing search online, but all of them seem to be outdated somehow. Even the official documentation does not make it clear for me.

For one reason or the other, I have to use a single `Activity` in my app, and handle the whole interaction with `Fragment`.

I am struggling on how to make the `SearchView` behave like I want to: I want the menu item to show the search bar at the top when i click it, then offer history and suggestions, then whenever something is searched, open a different `Fragment` with the results (actually, a `TabLayout` with three different result types) -- this is the way Youtube does I think.

I got to the point where searching for something brings another `Fragment` to the screen, but then I want that when the user clicks on the back arrow, the user is brought back to the previous `Fragment` (without it having to reload again the info -- there is endless scrolling so the user might have loaded tons of data): Whenever I click, first the action view for search disappears, then if I hit back again, the previous `Fragment` shows up but it's reloading its content.

this is my **setupSearch()** method:

```
private fun setupSearch(menu: Menu) {
        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_search)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))


        var searchEditTextId = R.id.search_src_text;
        var searchEditText = searchView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(searchEditTextId)
        var dropDownAnchor = searchView.findViewById<View>(searchEditText.dropDownAnchor)

        if (dropDownAnchor != null) {
            dropDownAnchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener { p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8 ->
                // screen width
                var screenWidthPixel = this@DashboardListActivity.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
                searchEditText.dropDownWidth = screenWidthPixel
            }
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                var searchSuggestion = SearchRecentSuggestions(this@DashboardListActivity, SearchHistoryProvider.AUTHORITY, SearchHistoryProvider.MODE)
                searchSuggestion.saveRecentQuery(query, null)

                supportFragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, SearchResultsContainerFragment.newInstance())
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .addToBackStack("SEARCH")
                .commit()
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })

        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener{
            override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return true
            }

        })

        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(object: SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {
            override fun onSuggestionSelect(position: Int): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSuggestionClick(position: Int): Boolean {
                return false
            }

        })
    }
```

Also, when displaying the suggestion list, it seems the `Activity` is somehow paused and resumed (I guess because it is implemented as a `dialog`?). This would not be a problem but I am keeping a video window always on top of all views (hence my need to do everything with `Fragment`) and the video stops for a split sec then continues. Is it possible to prevent that?

Search seemed like an easy task but its becoming kind of a nightmare. The official documentation says that i must create a different `Activity` that is "Searchable" but I cannot do that.

Comment: That's not a big issue. You just need to check which fragment is currently visible and send that `QueryText` into that fragment and filter your list of that visible fragment.

Comment: there seem to be multiple problems, could isolate the main one?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to reload the fragment(that contains the search) when you go back you have to change the replace fragment with add.  That is because replace does a remove (of any fragment) followed by an add(the new fragment).

Comment: @MichelReap, what's the next one?

Comment: I have a video window that displays at all times, when the search history shows up the video stops due to the activity onPAusing and onResuming

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these library as per your requirements :

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

https://github.com/lapism/SearchView